# nokogiri/open-uri how to parse multiple web addresses

Tags: ruby, uri, nokogiri

I'm trying to get data from a site that looks like this... http://www.site.com/thing/?word=(A word)
As anyone answering this question already knows, to open this, you need enter something like this... doc=Nokogiri::HTML (open('link to web adress')
I have multiple "areas" from the same site, where the only thing changing is the word after the = sign. Is there a way I could compile a list of the words and make it so that somehow I don't have to write out a bunch of doc=Nokogiri::HTML(open(link) things, I've tried some stuff already but I'm just not catching on. Thanks.

Comment: This is neither a nokogiri nor open-uri question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it seems like you want to do something like this:

```
words = ['apple', 'bannana', 'cucumber']

words.each do |word|
 address = "http://www.site.com/thing/?word=" + word
 doc=Nokogiri::HTML (open(address))
 // do more stuff with doc
end
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do, except I tried something like this and it says that I have a error with the undefined method each. What should I do?

Comment: Cool.  You should accept my answer then, so that others will know that it worked for you.  (And so I'll get some very valuable SO points!)

Comment: Alright I will, but I just need a little more help, when I do this it says there is an undefined method 'each', what to do know? I tried something very similar to what you gave me but I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Paste into the comments exactly what you did?  If you store a bunch of words in a Ruby array (like I did) it *will* have a method called each.  Are you using IRB or Pry to try out your code?

Comment: Yeah I had extra text on there on accident, here is what I did and it says there is an error with the array still?                                                      require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'

require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'

begin
 states=[["AL","AK","AZ","AR"]]
  states.each do |word|
  adress = "http://www.fastline.com/v100/find-farm-equipment-dealer-results.aspx?states=" + word
  doc=Nokogiri::HTML (open(adress))
  doc.xpath('//span[@class="copyLeft"]').first.to_s.delete('^0-9').to_i 
 end 
end

Comment: Get rid of one of the sets of brackets:
states = ["AL","AK","AZ","AR"]